# Making a foreign key User model extension in Django required

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am extending the Django User model to include a foreign key pointing at another model like so (just like it says in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)):

models.py:

```
class Ward(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Extending the user model
class WardMember(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ward.name
```

admin.py:

```
class WardMemberInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = WardMember
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'ward member'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (WardMemberInline, )

admin.site.register(Ward)

# Re-register UserAdmin to get WardMember customizations
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

When I create a new user in the admin interface I want this new `WardMember.ward` extension to be required. Currently it's not enforcing that. Here's what happens:

1. Create user succeeds without a ward
2. Create other records as user succeed
3. Edit user now won't let me save unless there is a ward selected

I'd really like #1 above to fail.

I've tried figuring out how to override `save()` for `User` using a proxy object but that's not working. I looked into the `pre_save` signal but the docs explicitly say that's not for vetoing saves.

What is the right approach?

Additional information:

- I'm using 1.4. I see that in 1.5 I can [extend the user class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) but I'm not in a position to update to 1.5 just yet.

---

**I ended up forging ahead with Django 1.5**, but I'll leave this here in case someone has a final answer to contribute that works with 1.4.

Comment: Why don't you extend `User` base model and add a foreign key to ward? That may do.

Comment: I see that I can do that with Django 1.5, but I'm on 1.4. Maybe I'll look into migrating, but I just have this one little thing to work out. (Question updated to include pertinent information)

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.3.1 I use this code and works fine:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FilterSearchQueries(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    query = models.TextField()
```